# How to pass the name in View Data instead of ID

Tags: drop-down-menu, attributes, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on an application on .NET Core MVC and I'd like to have the name of the navigated property "Hobbies" instead of the ID in my create view

I have this:

[image: dropdownlist showing DDL item ID]

And I would like this, intead:

[image: dropdownlist showing DDL item name]

That I manage to get with that code for the create action in the controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["HobbiesName"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Hobbies>(), "HobbiesName", "HobbiesName");
        return View();
    }
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("PersonID,PersonName,PersonSurname,HobbiesID")] Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(person);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["HobbieName"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Hobbies>(), "HobbiesID", "HobbiesName", person.HobbiesID);
        return View(person);
    }
```

And in the view :

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Hobbies.HobbiesName" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Hobbies.HobbiesName" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.HobbiesName"></select>
        </div>
```

But that doesn't work because, I need the ID.
Does anybody know how I can manage that?

Answer (score 0):

**The following worked for me:**

```
<select asp-for="Name" asp-items="@Model.NameList">
```

**In my view model:**

```
public string Name { get; set; }                   
public SelectList NameList { get; set; }
```

It is better to work with a view model and avoid ViewBag.
It is essential to have two different fields: the list of items (with their ids already there, behind the scenes), and a field representing the text (not the id) of the item selected